# How can I round decimal numbers in Java?

Tags: java

I know that in Java we have a lot of methods to round, but if my code returns the value

> 0.19998344639311716

And I need the value

> 0.2

If I use the method `Math.round()` it will return **0.0**

If I use `Math.ceil()` it will return **1.0**

What method I can use to return **0.2**?

Comment: If your code has those errors and they matter you probably should not be using floating point. Check out BigDecimal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always `Math.round(x*10) / 10` .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big decimal example:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(double_value).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```